# How to test a controller in Node.js using Chai, Sinon, Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I've been learning how to write better unit tests. I am working on a project where controllers follow the style of 'MyController' shown below. Basically an 'async' function that 'awaits' on many external calls and returns a status with the results. I have written a very basic test for an inner function 'dbResults'. However, I am unsure of how to go about testing if the entire controller function itself returns a certain value. In the example below. I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out what is the proper way to test the final result of a function such as 'getUserWithId'. The code written below is very close but not exactly what I have implemented. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Controller

```
export const MyController = {
  async getUserWithId(req, res) {
    let dbResults = await db.getOneUser(req.query.id);
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK', data: dbResults });
  }
}
```

Current Test

```
describe ('MyController Test', () => {
   describe ('getUserWithId should return 200', () => {
     before(() => {
       // create DB stub   
     });

     after(() => {
       // restore DB stub
     });

     it('should return status 200', async () => {
       req = // req stub
       res = // res stub

       const result = await MyController.getUserWithId(req, res);

       expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Wait. Wouldn't your controller throw an error `cannot call function status of undefined` because `res` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: You are correct. I was only providing pseudocode. I'm adding it in.

Comment: If you just want to test your controlloer function without actual implementation call of `getUserWithId` you can mock the `getUserWithId` function. 

If you want to check e2e implmenetation I would suggest creating  separate unit test for getUserWithId function by moving into itw own DAL layer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an `integration-test` for testing your controller rather than a `unit-test`.

`integration-test` threats the app as a black box where the network is the input (HTTP request) and 3rd party services as dependency that should be mocked (DB).

- Use `unit-test` for services, factories, and utils.
- Use `integration-test` for external interfaces like HTTP and WebSockets

You can add `e2e-test` as well but if you have only one component in your setup you `integration-test` will suffice.